# Does ASP.NET mean ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have worked with `ASP.NET MVC 5.0` and that is the **only** `ASP*`  technology I have ever seen or worked with. I even searched on Goolge and got more confused.

For example in this book, what are they teaching? When they say ASP.NET, does it mean ASP.NET Web Forms? 
[image]

Mainly my question is this: When I see ASP.NET , does it mean ASP.NET WebForms?  ( Unless it is ASP.NET core or MVC, those two I know ) but I get confused between ASP.NET and ASP.NET WebForms?

Many years ago one time I dragged dropped some buttons and text boxes on a ASP.NET page, it was `VS2003` :) I think, so was that ASP.NET WebForms and this book above is still the continuation of that one? Or we can use some sort of `ASP.NET` that is not `WebForms` or `MVC` or `Core` too?

Comment: In general terminology, Asp.net means "Asp.Net Web Forms"

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET is a technology which is developed by Microsoft. You use it 2 different ways which are ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC. These are pattern and they have changable usage for the user. They have many layer. 
For easy example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_introduction.htm  That's All :))

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is a framework for creating server side web applications so it's set of tools , API ,  libraries ...etc , web forms is just part from this framework , other parts include ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web Pages, and ASP.NET Single Page Applications.

check this :
https://www.asp.net/web-forms/what-is-web-forms

Answer (score 1):

If we turned back the time, ASP.NET was of course WebForms initially in 2001, so we don't even need to explicitly call it WebForms.

The meaning of ASP.NET only changed when Microsoft published ASP.NET MVC (and later Web API/SignalR/Web Pages), some time around 2010. From then on ASP.NET is the umbrella term to cover them all, as well as WebForms.

Recently ASP.NET Core was created as a brand new platform, different from all previous frameworks. Thus, IMHO ASP.NET Core != ASP.NET.

Back to the book cover, it should mean all things under ASP.NET 4.5, which includes WebForms/MVC/Web API/SignalR/Web Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have that textbook and the author presents the material using ASP.NET WebForms.  I believe he covers MVC but in short detail; I can't remember offhand.

As for the other answers, yes, ASP.NET is Microsoft's web programming framework.  There are basically three primary technologies that you can leverage: ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API (actually an extension of ASP.NET MVC), and ASP.NET WebForms.  You can of course create other types of apps as well, such as SPAs, but these are definitely the primary technologies available to you.  The nice thing about these is that you aren't necessarily tied to one technology - you can mix and match different technologies in one solution.

If you are completely new to ASP.NET, I would suggest you look at Microsoft's tutorials on building ASP.NET Core applications so you can leverage the cross-platform technologies Microsoft is heading towards.  You mentioned that you've worked with ASP.NET MVC and .NET Core, so I'm assuming you're also aware that you can leverage ASP.NET Web API there as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

Hope that helps.